# Django slow autoreload due to check_url_config system check

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.9

My load and autoreload on python manage.py runserver is taking a lot of time. (25seconds+). I did a bit of digging and it seems to be stuck on "Performing system checks..". To investigate more, I added timer on each of the check functions.

```
C:\Programs\Python35-32\python.exe manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

self.check: check_default_cache_is_configured 0.0
self.check: check_duplicate_template_settings 0.0
self.check: check_all_models 0.028018712997436523
self.check: check_model_signals 0.0
self.check: check_setting_app_dirs_loaders 0.0
self.check: check_url_config 25.260559558868408
self.check: check_admin_app 0.0
self.check: check_user_model 0.0
self.check: check_generic_foreign_keys 0.0010006427764892578
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
self.check: 25.289578914642334
self.check_migrations: 0.08856558799743652
June 28, 2016 - 15:43:08
Django version 1.9.6, using settings 'mar16_cookifi_com.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

I found that in check\urls.py, resolver.url_patterns is taking a long time.

```
def check_resolver(resolver):
    """
    Recursively check the resolver.
    """
    from django.core.urlresolvers import RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver
    warnings = []
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
        if isinstance(pattern, RegexURLResolver):
```

1. I am not sure how urlresolver.url_patterns is taking a long time. I would appreciate some help in understanding why it takes 25 seconds to load the url_patters. What can I do to reduce this.
2. At the very least, I would like to disable check_url_config. Solution for 1 is more preferred.

Added:

I manually disabled the check function in django code. 
[Edit] Actually it just delayed the problem to the first load, which took 25 seconds.

```
@register(Tags.urls)
def check_url_config(app_configs, **kwargs):
    return []
    if getattr(settings, 'ROOT_URLCONF', None):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver
        resolver = get_resolver()
        return check_resolver(resolver)
    return []
```

The time reduces to sub second:

```
C:\Programs\Python35-32\python.exe manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

self.check: check_default_cache_is_configured 0.0
self.check: check_duplicate_template_settings 0.0
self.check: check_all_models 0.028048038482666016
self.check: check_model_signals 0.0
self.check: check_setting_app_dirs_loaders 0.0
self.check: check_url_config 0.0
self.check: check_admin_app 0.0
self.check: check_user_model 0.0
self.check: check_generic_foreign_keys 0.0
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
self.check: 0.028048038482666016
self.check_migrations: 0.06304526329040527
June 28, 2016 - 16:24:36
Django version 1.9.6, using settings 'mar16_cookifi_com.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

But i would like to have a solution where I do not modify django code.

**After 1 more hour:**

Found the cause of the problem. The url file is loading all our views. One of the view recently added a ML module which takes 25 seconds to train. Making the ML module lazy reduced the loading time to a second.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a [`SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS) which prevents the warnings from being displayed, but it does not have a hook to prevent the check from running.

You could prevent the URL checks by commenting out [the import](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5fe1c92250017110430c7c2153cfd8776e4c7064/django/core/checks/__init__.py#L20) in the Django source code.

However, I'm not sure that this will speed up your application. When the URL patterns are loaded, Django imports the views at the same time. If you disable the URL checks, then Django will still need to load the URL config later, so I suspect that you will see a similar delay. You should investigate further to find out which included `urls.py` files and views are taking a long time to load.

Comment: I tried disabling the check by modifying the code. manage.py now loads in milliseconds. But I would prefer a way which does not touches django code.

Comment: As I said, Django does not have a hook to prevent the check from running. I would dig deeper into why the check takes so long to run, rather than disabling it. My guess is that there's an issue in your urls config or views.

Comment: Found the cause of the problem. The url file is loading all our views. One of the view recently added a ML module which takes 25 seconds to train. Making the ML module lazy reduced the loading time to a second. Thanks a lot for helping.